# Is there a way to force close Steam on Steam Deck from an app that runs on Proton?

Tags: linux, operating-system, steam, wine

I'm working on an installer for a mod that requires adding a launch option to a game on Steam (a dll override of dinput8). However the only way I found to programatically add this launch option is by editing the localconfig.vdf file that contains the launch options for owned games. This file does not seem to be editable when Steam is running (the client doesn't read this file while running, and will replace any change when it is closed). Therefore I'd like to automatize the installation of my mod so that Steam gets closed before proceeding with the installation and writing in the vdf file.

Sadly I was not able to find a way to know if Steam is running because (as I understand it, I don't own a deck myself), my installer is running on a different OS (windows) than Steam. Is there a way to know Steam is running on the other OS and kill it somehow from the windows OS my installer is running on?